# How to automatically delete records from database after a specific time in Django

Tags: django-2.2

I have a model named 'Complaint' with numerous entries and I want to delete the entry if it is in database for more than 3 days. How can I do that is there any query for specifying the time. I'm also storing the time at which the entry was stored. This is my models.py file.

```
complaint_for = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=COMPLAINT_CHOICES, default='Misbehave')
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I also think that the best way to do this is on the DB site. More info about the dB you are using?

Comment: I'm using SQLite. @t_e_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I have never worked worked with Django, but as far as I know, a good solution to delete records after a certain time interval, is to run automatically a database script. In your case, I can imagine that you have somewhere in your db-table a column which is named `creation_time` or something like that and then with your script you can just check if the difference between the current time and the  `creation_time` is more or equal to the specified time interval. If so, the script deletes the record. In order to run such a script automatically, you can start a `cron job` . You can read more on the topic how to delete records with sql [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/automatically-delete-row-after-10-ninutes-after-creation/4867) and [here](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/) on the topic cron jobs.

Comment: Yes that gave me the idea

Comment: @Nouman Malik, you could upvote my answer or choose it as the best one in order to show others that my proposal was helpful. 